# jQuery insertAfter from iFrame into Parent

Tags: jquery, iframe

Inside the parent file I have:

```
<p id="successmsg">Text.</p>        
<iframe src="file.php" name="calcFrame"></iframe>
```

Inside file.php is:

```
<script>
jQuery(window.parent.document).ready(function() { jQuery('<p>Text to be inserted.</p>').insertAfter('#successmsg'); });
</script>
```

The script has no affect. I've tried jQuery(document). I'm unsure what if anything I need to do like window.parent.document to let jQuery know the id is inside the parent page.

Comment: You can't bind to the ready of the parent window's document (and it doesn't make sense to since it will already be ready). The insertAfter should work assuming #successmsg is in the iframe, not the parent. If you want the one in the parent, you will have to navigate from `window.parent.document` to find it.

Comment: And that's what I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$('#successmsg', window.parent.document).after('<p>Text to be inserted.</p>');
```

[**Jsbin example**](http://jsbin.com/ifubur/1/edit)

Comment: Nothing happened with this as well.

Comment: Turns out a wordpress plugin was blocking the jquery file from being included from non-theme files. Darkajax's solution worked when this was fixed.